# How do I delete columns where the average of the column already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the example below, Column C should be deleted because it already exists (Column A should remain)

type(df): pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
A B C

1 2 1

0 2 0

3 2 3
```

I tried creating a dictionary to later delete repeated values but got stuck

```
dict_test = {}

for each_column in df:
    dict_test[each_column] = df[[each_column]].mean()

dict_test
```

The result came out to be dtype: float64, 'A' : A 1.33333

The problem above is that the dictionary is storing the 'Key and Value' in the Value section so I can't compare Values to one another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `df.mean().drop_duplicates()` and pandas indexing:

```
In [30]: df[df.mean().drop_duplicates().index]
Out[30]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  0  2
2  3  2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I saw someone answered earlier as well but couldn't find his answer after refreshing. 

Both answers are very helpful. How do I accept the answer - sorry first time here. For reference someone else said to df.T.drop_duplicates().T

Comment: @Gary also, the previous answer *will not* remove columns with differing elements, but the same average.  I'd imagine that's why it was deleted.

Comment: Just in case anyone's wondering what the previous answer was, here it is: `df.T.drop_duplicates().T`. I removed it because I realized what chrisz is pointing out above.